# How can access the facebook country database

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

How can access the facebook country database?

Is there any way to access through the fql queries.

If anybody knows,let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by "country database"?

Comment: Do you mean the map-information? Geolocations and such? Were can I find this country-database at Facebook?

Comment: presently in my site,i am showing up cities/coutry from site db.but i want to display from the FB

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to retrieve list of countries available to users as option to specify their locations like Hometown or Current City.

There is however lists of cities for advertising targeting purposes (probably outdated):

1. [All Cities](http://developers.facebook.com/attachment/all_cities_final.csv)
2. [Major Cities](http://developers.facebook.com/attachment/major_cities_final.csv)

Locations on Facebook is just Facebook Pages with `category` *City*, *Country*, *Regional* (and probably some other categories as well, I'm not aware of any full list of those).

Your options (if you want only official data from Facebook):

- Using list from links above (they contain *Country* for every city listed).
- Graph API search with `type=page` and later filtering only specific categories.
  Something like `GET https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Australia&type=page`
  Be warned that you'll get a lot of results so this is most inefficient way for getting this information...
- Using Ads API for [Retrieving Autocomplete Data](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/get-autocomplete-data/)
  For countries `GET https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=au&type=adcountry`

You may also want to read similar question [List of Cities by Country](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/1794833/list-of-cities-by-country)